# esc последовательность в cout

Tags: c++, linux, g++, esc

Этот код все делает правильно: очищает экран, и вывод с первой строки, первой позиции ячейки:

```
write(1, "\x1b[999B\x1b[999C", 12);
//Тут будет код вычисляющий размер терминала(знаю про ioctl)
write(1, "\x1b[H", 3);
write(1, "\x1b[J", 3);
output();//посимвольно выводит в stdout из массива
```

Но если заменить первую строку на эту:

```
cout << "\x1b[999B\x1b[999C";
```

То вывод будет начинаться где-то с середины терминала(по-крайней мере в моем).
Сразу подумал, что cout добавляет в конец `\0`, но строка

```
write(1, "\x1b[999B\x1b[999C\0", 13);
```

ничего не меняет, все работает так же четко.

P.s. забыл упомянуть важную деталь, что терминал настроен в сыром режиме

Comment: `flush()` сделать не забыл после вывода?

Comment: Возможно, правильнее было бы управлять терминалом через curses.

Comment: кстати, какой вообще смысл ты вкладываешь в `"\x1b[999B\x1b[999C"`?

Comment: в комменте написано, там будут команды для вычисления координат, которые будут меньше или равны 999, но максимальны в данном окне.

Comment: @SergG, для этого курсор не нужно двигать... и обычно все удовлетворяются `getenv("COLUMNS")`... ЗЫ: с `cout` УМВР как и ожидалось, так что если какое-то неожиданное поведение сохраняется, предлагаю дать [mcve]... ЗЗЫ: если отвечать без упоминания, то уведомления в некоторых случаях не приходят.